# What websites allow users to login with an arbitrary OpenID Connect identity?

Tags: openid-connect, openid-provider

I'm building an OpenID Connect Provider (OP) but so far I haven't found any public websites on which to try it out. I had intended on adding it to my StackOverflow profile only to find out that poor ol' SO uses an [obsolete library](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) ([the repo is dead](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/392)) that only supports OpenID 1.1 and 2.0 but not OpenID Connect! And http://openid.net/ does not appear to have a list of any such sites with the exception of its own [conformance testing](http://openid.net/certification/testing/).

Any thoughts, references, or answers as to where one can go to play with my OP?

**UPDATE**: I'll try to be more specific. I'm looking for websites like StackOverflow or LiveJournal which allow you to login with any OpenID. I have yet to find a public client that does this with the exception of OpenID.net's conformance testing. An ideal client would implement discovery to translate the identity string into a WebFinger call, get the provider metadata, dynamically register with the provider, and finally perform the authentication.

Comment: I'd like to add that sites supporting Google Sign-In are not helpful to anyone attempting to broaden the field of identity providers. They might be using the *protocol* but the site is still locked in to a single provider which (IMHO) defeats one of the principles of OpenID

Answer (score 0):

For testing it would be best to use the (beta) RP certification suite from: http://openid.net/certification/rp_testing/

Mitre has another test suite at: https://mitreid.org/rp/

There are plenty of websites out there that support OIDC. Anything that supports Google+ Signin is an OpenID Connect Provider. But it is usually fixed to one or more statically configured providers, so not suitable for random testing.

Comment: I've seen the assertion about plenty of websites and support, but I have yet to see it in my searching. Say, a forum website or shopping or anything where normally to register you login with Google or Facebook but I would like to try logging in with OiDC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised how difficult it is to find an answer to this question. What
follows is my current understanding of the state of OIDC, based on my recent and
small amount of research into the topic. Even though it isn't an answer to the OP's original question, I hope that it will be useful entry point to others who've just started thinking about this topic. (Also, what I've written is too big for a comment)

[This comment on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=34095084)
laments the current state of OIDC, in particular that one can't sign in to major
sites using a self-hosted identity provider (this is a use case I'm interested
in). [A reply in this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=34095302)
points out that there are OIDC standards for identity provider discovery, so
this thing we want is at least possible.

I read through the standards and checked what I learned against some popular OpenID Connect providers: Gmail, Outlook, Apple ID, Facebook, and GitLab. Here's what I learned.

[OpenID Connect Discovery
1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) defines "Issuer
Discovery", which uses
[WebFinger](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7033) (mentioned by the OP) to find an OpenID
provider given an email or URL. Major OpenID providers don't seem to support
this.

For example,

- https://gmail.com/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct:person@gmail.com&rel=http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer
  and
- https://outlook.com/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct:person@outlook.com&rel=http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer
- https://icloud.com/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct:person@icloud.com&rel=http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer
- https://www.facebook.com/.well-known/webfinger?resource=https://facebook.com/person&rel=http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer

are all not found. Applications that want to use these providers are forced
to hard-code their locations.

Of the OpenID Connect providers I investigated, only GitLab supports WebFinger:

- https://gitlab.com/.well-known/webfinger?resource=https://gitlab.com/person&rel=http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer

[OpenID
Connect Dynamic Client Registration
1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html)) defines an
interface for programmatic OAuth 2.0 client registration (i.e. assignment of a
client ID and client secret). OpenID providers who support dynamic client
registration need to include a `registration_endpoint` in their OpenID
configuration. Again, major sites seems to omit this:

- https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
- https://appleid.apple.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
- https://www.facebook.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
- https://gitlab.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

None of the above return a `registration_endpoint` key. Supporting
these providers requires manual OAuth 2.0 registration for each.

---

My prediction is that major web applications that have optimised for increasing
their user count won't implement arbitrary OpenID login. It's a extra feature
that can't be implemented in terms of previous work (because none of the major
providers support dynamic registration) and only marginally grows the set of
potential users.

So I'd expect that web apps concerned with open web standards and
decentralisation are the most likely to support arbitrary OpenID login. I
checked [Element](https://app.element.io/#/login) (a
[Matrix](https://matrix.org/) web client), and it only supports a fixed set of
providers. [mastodon.social](https://mastodon.social/) (a
[Mastodon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastodon_(social_network)) server)
creates an account on the server, and that identity can't be used on other
Mastodon servers.

Answer (score -1):

Found a list,

here it is:

aol / aim , blogger , claimid , google , livejournal , myspace , sxipper , verisign , vidoop , wordpress , yahoo , myopenid , getopenid

If desired, see [this](http://openidexplained.com/get#providers-table) web-page for the source of this list (has links to the list sites on it)... :

Or if that is not quite what you want,

[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect) may be it...  (there is a (different) list on that page)... :

Comment: This is a list of OpenID identity providers, which is not what the OP is asking for.